# Define default figure size in ggplot via theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

Being used to python, I had different design dictionaries to ensure best possible fit to the output medium (e. g. PowerPoint vs. TeX-Document).

I'd like to do the same in R, so that I could change the figure size just by changing the theme. So if I add `+ theme_pdf` I get a different figure size in contrast to `+ theme_ppt`.

I found a solution for every other aspect (linewidth etc.) but cannot figure out how to do it for the figure size. I know that I can put figure size in the `ggsave()` command, but I prefer to do so in a theme, if anyhow possible in R.

Comment: You can use `theme_set` to use the current `theme` for all the following plots.

Comment: Size is a property of the plotting device, not the plot itself. This is not something you can control with a plot theme. You're better off creating your own helper function to wrap `ggsave`.

Comment: Okay, obviously a difference to Python. But a ggsave-Wrapping is a good idea. thx!. Would you mind to create a short answer? I'd like to flag it as correct.